# Python- Check terminal shell if changed from the environmental shell

Tags: python, linux

When a terminal is opened, the environmental shell is set. If I then type "csh" it starts running a c shell as a program within the bash terminal. My question is, from a python script, how can I check to determine if csh has been executed prior to starting the python script.

THanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? We don't provide code -- we help solving errors!

Comment: I have tried:   os.system("env ps -p $$") and cmd = "csh" and then a subprocess call on cmd

Comment: I have tried:   os.system("env ps -p $$"). If you type 'env ps -f $$', it should show the shell your in, but this does not work from a python script. I also tried a subprocess call; cmd = "csh" and then a subprocess call on cmd. This stops the script cold.

I also tried the suggestion below, which allows me to set the shell to /bin/csh. However, I have scripts that only work if I type csh prior to running the python script, so this did not work

Comment: I also tried first executing csh from a terminal and then os.system('echo $0') from my python script, but rather than printing csh, it prints sh

Answer (score 1):

You can check the shell environment by using

```
import os
shell = os.environ['SHELL']
```

Then you can make sure `shell` is set to `/bin/csh`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.getppid()` to find the [parent PID](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18166/3330), and `ps` to find the name of the command:

```
import subprocess
import os
ppid = os.getppid()
out = subprocess.check_output(['ps', '--format', '%c', '--pid', str(ppid)])
print(out.splitlines()[-1])
```

---

```
% csh
% script.py
csh

% bash
(dev)13:53:04 unutbu@buster:~% script.py
bash
```

Note that the parent process may not be a shell. If I run the code from an IPython session launched inside emacs, then the parent is emacs:

```
In [170]: ppid = os.getppid()
    out = subprocess.check_output(['ps', '--format', '%c', '--pid', str(ppid)])
    print(out.splitlines()[-1])
In [172]: emacs
```